# Laravel : fill() and update() not work when i use $request->all() but work in fill($request->only('...'))

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I have some column in JSON format.
for example 'Bank' column in database be like this :

```
{"name":"Bank of America", "card":"6037...", "account":"321354...", "expire" : "2018-12-09"}
```

i used Laravel **Cast** to in Model like this :

```
protected $casts = [
    'bank' => 'array',
]
```

In view my form fileds named by these :

```
<input name="bank[name]" ...>
<input name="bank[account]" ...>
<input name="bank[card]" ...>
```

Now when i want to update Bank in database. when i use this

```
$profile->fill($request->only('bank'));
$profile->save();
```

every things work OK. but when i use this

```
$profile->fill($request->all());
$profile->save();
```

i got this error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bank[card]' in 'field list' (SQL: update...

What's wrong ?!

***Solution with thanks to @Jonas ::***

> it was the problem : in Requests->myFormRequest i cleaned my data
>   whit this :
>
> ```
> if( $this->bank['card'] )  { $input['bank[card]']  = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $this->bank['card']); }
> ```
>
> and it was wrong for arrays. i changed it to this and every thing
>   worked perfectly.
>
> ```
> if( $this->bank['card'] )  { $input['bank']['card']  = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $this->bank['card']); }
> ```

Comment: please include output of `$request->all()` in question

Comment: Did you add `bank` to `$fillable`?

Comment: `protected $guarded = [
        'user_id', 'username', 'password', 'status', 'type',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'bank' => 'array',
        'post' => 'array',
        'house'=> 'array',
    ];
`

Comment: What's the value of `$fillable`?

Comment: @Jonas
 Nothing. there is no `$fillable`.
based on Laravel documet :  _"you will need to specify either a fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default."_ 
[Laravel.Com](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: What's the result of `dd($request->all());`?

Comment: `array:22 [▼
  "_token" => "..."
  "post" => array:2 [▼
    "address" => "بسیب"
    "code" => null
  ]
  "bank" => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "سیبسب"
    "card" => "6037-9971-6823-7312"
    "account" => "031323213213"
  ]
  "family_counts" => "3"
  "house" => array:2 [▶]
  "bank[card]" => "6037997168237312"
  "bank[account]" => "031323213213"
]
`

Comment: also i use this code for clean input in my formRequest :
`if( $this->bank['card'] )  { $input['bank[card]']     = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $this->bank['card']); } `
`if( $this->bank['account']){ $input['bank[account]']  = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $this->bank['account']); } `
`if(isset($input)){ $this->merge($input);} `

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but in the error message I see bank[cart].
In your html there is bank[card], maybe its just a typo.